# How to filter keywords in VBA, including keywords that may not be found?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, criteria

I want to filter a report that may or may not have five keywords in Column B (red, blue, orange, green and yellow) These keywords are associated with numbers in a different column

I want to take the sum of the column associated with each keyword on the generated report

However, the report may or may not have all five keywords; day over day may be different, with or without yellow for instance

I took the sum of the first keyword (a criterion) in Column C to paste elsewhere and it works!

But once I search for the second keyword an error occurs : This can't be applied to a single cell, select a single cell in a range (Run-time error 1004) . Any thoughts?

---

Second question is how do set my range (C2:C1000) and (B2:B1000) and  for all filtered numbers in column C and keywords in column B, since I can have over 1000 rows or rows whose location is beyond 1000

```
Set rng = ws.Range("C1:C" & lastrow) 'but to no avail

Sub filterVBA()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim visibleTotal As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C1000")

    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="red"

    visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    Windows("Book6").Activate
    Range("A1").Value = visibleTotal

    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="blue"

    Windows("Book6").Activate
    Range("A2").Value = visibleTotal
End Sub
```

Comment: `SpecialCells` throws an error if no cells are found, you need to handle that.  Assign the `SpecialCells` call to a Range variable wrapped in an error handler, then proceed only when something is found.

Comment: And [see this about Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Regarding the range, use the `End(xlUp)` technique

Comment: the second criterion does exist in the report, but I don't know why that error pops up

Comment: vba flags at the line Selection.Autofilter

Comment: I don't see where you have explicitly declared and used the sheet you are attempting to filter.  Using properties and methods like Select, ActiveSheet, Activate, etc. is often a cause for these kinds of errors, and has been discussed ad nauseum in this group.  See the link posted by @chrisneilsen  Your method is probably trying to execute on the wrong worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

1. Use of `Select` gives unexpected results (the second Filter will be applied to `Windows("Book6")`).  Use Variables to reference the sheets and ranges.
2. Resetting the AutoFilter is fragile, if one doesn't already exists it will actually set a filter.  Detect if a Filter exists before clearing it.
3. Clean up range selection.
4. Missing `visibleTotal =` after second filter

---

```
Sub filterVBA()
    Dim visibleTotal As Long
    Dim wsTable As Worksheet
    Dim wsReport As Worksheet
    Dim rTable As Range
    Dim rReport As Range

    'Get reference to Table
    Set wsTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With wsTable
        Set rTable = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    End With

    'Get Reference to Reult sheet
    Set wsReport = Application.Workbooks("Book6").ActiveSheet
    Set rReport = wsReport.Cells(1, 1)

    'Clear Filter if it exists
    If wsTable.AutoFilterMode Then
        rTable.AutoFilter
    End If
    'Set Filter
    rTable.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="red"

    visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rTable.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    'Alternative formula
    'visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, rTable.Columns(2))

    'Report result
    rReport.Value = visibleTotal
    Set rReport = rReport.Offset(1, 0)

    'Next Filter
    rTable.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="white"
    visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rTable.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    rReport.Value = visibleTotal
    Set rReport = rReport.Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

<sub>Note on why there is no Error Handling around `SpecialCells`</sub>

<sub>Because the range SpecialCells is applied to includes the header row, and a AutoFilter never hides the header, in this case `SpecialCells` will always return a result .</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your feedback Chris

I got my answer looking like this and works well:

Sub filterVBA()

```
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim visibleTotal As Long


 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Set rng = ws.Range("D:D")

 If ws.FilterMode = True Then
         ws.ShowAllData
 End If


 Application.ScreenUpdating = False


 ws.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Yellow"


 visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

 Windows("Book6").Activate
 Range("A1").Value = visibleTotal



 ws.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Red"
 visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

 Windows("Book6").Activate
 Range("A5").Value = visibleTotal


 ws.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Green"
 visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

 Windows("Book6").Activate
 Range("A10").Value = visibleTotal


 ws.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Blue"
 visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

 Windows("Book6").Activate
 Range("A15").Value = visibleTotal


 If ws.FilterMode = True Then
         ws.ShowAllData
 End If

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub